# Vector subspace projection

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the projection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can I do this by adding the projections to each basis vector, even if the basis vectors are not orthogonal?
Specifically, projecting $x$ onto $V$, can I define the projection $$\operatorname{proj}_V(x) = \sum_i \frac {v_i\cdot x}{v_i\cdot v_i}v_i$$ for basis vectors $v_i$?

Comment: [How to format your questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

You need an orthogonal basis.

Let's make a simple counterexample with $n=2$. The subspace is $U=\langle e_1\rangle$. Consider the basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ where
$$
v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
v_2=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
For $x=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ we have
$$
\frac{v_1\bullet x}{v_1\bullet v_1}v_1
+
\frac{v_2\bullet x}{v_2\bullet v_2}v_2
=
\frac{0}{1}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}
+
\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\1/2\end{bmatrix}
$$
while the orthogonal projection of $x$ on $U$ is clearly the zero vector.

You need an orthogonal basis.